# Sqlite query not working

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to get all row details for a particular row type.

```
Select * from MainTable where JOB1=@Paint
```

It's not working. I tried with more options but not got succes. Can anyone tell me what is the correct format in Objective-C?

complete code is like

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    //const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM MainTable"; ??it is working

    const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM MainTable where JOB1='Paint'";//but not this one


    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    NSLog(@"query set");

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSString *job = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
            NSString *image = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            NSString *tools = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            NSString *materials = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
            NSString *people = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];
            NSString *safety = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];
            NSLog(@"%@",job);
            NSLog(@"image %@",image);
            NSLog(@"tools %@",tools);
            NSLog(@"materials %@",materials);
            NSLog(@"people %@",people);
            NSLog(@"safety %@",safety);
```

Comment: why is it not working? what errors you get? also, show how you are binding this query, please...

Answer (score 0):

you can fire queries for SQLite db using firefox addon SQLite manager

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

same query you can write in program. If still it is not running please post your code snippet.